# Are connect operations required to enforce the order of execution in openMDAO?

Tags: openmdao

I tried to wrap three external codes with OpenMDAO using a component with no params and no unknowns.  This is because the three codes only take input files and output files, and there is no need to "connect" an input variable to an output variable.  However, the codes run out of sequence (because obviously, they have no dependency information). I then saw the proper way to do this is to use an ExternalCodeComponent, but even then, we still have to connect an input to an output via the connect call.

Is this the only way to specify a dependency, by using the connect method on one components output and another's input?  It seems redundant to have to pass the output to the second component when the output is already in the input file to the next component.  If it is mandatory, will it work to just send dummy values over the other component that are never used, simply to define the dependency?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the execution order for subsystems in a Group with the set order method.

```
def set_order(self, new_order):
    """ Specifies a new execution order for this system. This should only
    be called after all subsystems have been added.

    Args
    ----
    new_order : list of str
        List of system names in desired new execution order.
    """
```

If you want to see the current order for that system, you can call:

```
my_system.list_order()
```

You do have to be careful, since you can use `set_order` to make things run in an out-of-dataflow-order.

Note, this was a quick solution to your question, but I think that it is probably generally better for OpenMDAO to have some idea of the underlying dataflow so that other features such as the dataflow viewer show things correctly. Obviously you can make that work by passing something nominally into and out of the isolated component. Also, if you are doing gradient optimization, the connections will also keep OpenMDAO from excluding this portion of the model as not relevant in the derivative calculation.

Comment: Can set_order (or for that matter, does OpenMDAO) support running two components who both only depend on the output from a previous component simultaneously, or does each component have to be executed serially (in which case, set_order could enforce the order). How is the order set when a connect is made from code A's output to both code B and C's output?  Is it the order in which the connects are made?

Comment: If you want to execute two (or more) components simultaneously, put the parallel-executing components in a ParallelGroup (as opposed to the standard Group).  You'll have to run with MPI.

Comment: you can run multiple components in parallel by using a parallel group. Here are some docs that show how to do that: http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/usr-guide/examples/parallel_multi_point.html#running-multi-point-in-parallel

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid MPI in this particular case.  I am aware of the MPI piece though.  Thanks.